# Can't pass the value to the other form

Tags: c#

the value of filteredSymptoms is rashes, cough, diarrhea and when passing these values of filteredSymptoms to another form, the value of filteredSymptoms is not being passed to the form2 (this is the second form). What part of my code is wrong or missing something?

Form1

```
FinalScreen showForm = new FinalScreen();
showForm.checkedSymptoms = filteredSymp;
```

Form2

```
public string checkedSymptoms { get; set; }
label1.Text = checkedSymptoms;
```

Comment: what's the issue on FinalScreen is your checkedSymptoms null?

Comment: Is this for WPF, WebForms or something else? Please add correct tag for better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an overload constructor on FinalScreen

```
    public FinalScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public FinalScreen(string checkedSymptoms)
        :base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CheckedSymptoms = checkedSymptoms;
    }

    public string CheckedSymptoms { get; set; }

    private void FinalScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = CheckedSymptoms;
    }
```

Then

```
    FinalScreen showForm = new FinalScreen(filteredSymp);
```

Comment: what is the use of :base? and where should I put the   FinalScreen showForm = new FinalScreen(checkedSymptoms ); in the form1?

Comment: That call your base constructor if you have a Base Form

Comment: and where should I put the   FinalScreen showForm = new FinalScreen(checkedSymptoms ); in the form1?

Comment: Yes in form1 and probably you have to call `showForm.Show();` or  `showForm.ShowDialog();` after that

Comment: in the form1 it says that the (checkedSymptoms) does not exist in current context

Comment: @RandomUser07 replace  filteredSymp with checkedSymptoms

Comment: @MihirDave in what part?

Comment: @RandomUser07 `FinalScreen showForm = new FinalScreen(filteredSymp);`

Comment: @RandomUser07 in form1 where you have defined filteredSymp

Comment: why cant I pass the value I received from other class to my current private void?

Comment: Private void not accessible from other class, change it to Public